# django: how to access only first error message in form.errors?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-forms

I have a model called Users and I have a form for that model called UsersForm. In my views.py, I created a version of UsersForm, like so

```
form = UsersForm()
if reqest.method == POST:
    form = UsersForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    c.update({'form':form})
    return render_to_response('home_page.html', c)
```

Now, my home_page.html is this:

```
<html>
    <body>

    <form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
    </form>

    {% if form.errors %}
        {% for field in form %}
            <p> {{field.errors}} </p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

So, what I want is, I want to display only the first error in {{ field.errors}}.
What I was thinking was something like:

```
    {% if form.errors %}
        {% for field in form %}
            <p> {{field.errors}} </p> {{ break}}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

but there is no break in the django template language, right? I also tried thinking about using {% for field in form|slice:":1" %} but that wouldn't work either. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7):

You can index lists in a django template by using the dot notation:

```
{{ field.errors.0 }}
```

Be sure to check that there is at least 1 error before doing that though, or you will get an Index out of range error.

Comment: Hm, it's not working. what I did was {% if field.errors %} <p> {% field.errors.0 %} {% endif %}.. I also tried replace "if field.errors".. just as a clarification, I don't want to display the first error in the every field, I want to just display the first field error in general.

Comment: Would `{{ form.errors.0 }}` do it? At the top of my head, I can't remember if that has all the errors, or just the form-level errors.

Comment: Hm it didn't work, doesn't give any errors even though I purposely am making errors :/ what I tried was {% if form.errors %} {{ form.errors.0 }} {% endif %}

Comment: I know that you can do {% for field in form %} {{ field.errors.0 }} {% endfor %} but that just displays the first error in each field. I just want it to return just one (the first) error it comes across and nothing else for any other field regardless of if there are more field errors or not.

Answer (score 0):

Take the template tag route.

Here's a sample template tag:

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter(name='show_error')
def show_error(dictionary):
    try:
        return dictionary.values()[0][0]
    except (TypeError,IndexError,AttributeError):
        return 'tip: try again'
```

And use it in your template like so:

```
{% if form.errors %}{{ form.errors|show_error }}</span>{% endif %}
```

Comment: Got it working with one small change: `list(dictionary.values())[0][0]`